# React Hooks + window.addEventListener in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to `console.log` the html element where the user is typing.

To do that I've implemented the following hook:

```
export const useGetActiveElement = () => {

const [activeElement, setActiveElement] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  if (window){
    window.addEventListener('keyup', setCorrectElement);
  }
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', setCorrectElement);
  }
}, [])

const setCorrectElement = (element) => {
  if(element.target.tagName === 'INPUT' || element.target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') {
    setActiveElement(element.target)
  }
}

return activeElement}
```

```
export default () => {
        const activeElement = useGetActiveElement()

        console.log(activeElement)  <==== Here! Only prints the value 2 or 3 times... 

        return <AnotherComponent />
}
```

For some reason I don't understand, the value is printed a couple of times in the console, but at some point, it just doesn't print anymore.

I'm not sure if this is a Ref issue... But couldn't find a reasonable explanation.

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your initial render, your hook's inner state initialises with `undefined`.

When you press a key, you enter your callback and attempt to set the state to the HTML element. React does several attempts of optimisation, and will compare the old state to the new state.  If the values are different, it will schedule a rerender of any component which uses this hook.  As `undefined` and an HTML element are different, React will cause a rerender of your component and your console.log message will display the current element.

---

When you press a key a 2nd time, you will attempt to set the state to the HTML element again.  This time however, this value as the previous state, which means previous components which used this state don't need to rerender.

However there is a known quirk with React's Concurrency and React will actually render one more time to figure out which version is currently committed.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17474#issuecomment-560942800

> We don't cheaply know which of two versions is currently committed. When this ambiguity happens we have to over render once and after that we know that both versions are the same and it doesn't matter.

So your component will render a 2nd time and again, your console.log message will display the current element.

---

When you press a key for a 3rd time however, React will again notice it's the same reference, but this time will not rerender your component.

Thus your component will not rerender a 3rd time, and your console log will not display.

Comment: Thanks! That's was a part of the problem. The activeElement was the same after the second type, therefore the component was not rerendered.   Something important to add is that if you try to use the state WITHIN the listener you MUST use REFs, otherwise you'll always get the old value, hence the component won't rerender => [link](https://medium.com/geographit/accessing-react-state-in-event-listeners-with-usestate-and-useref-hooks-8cceee73c559)